# Ansible. Find mac address and put in into variable

Tags: regex, ansible

```
tasks:
       - name: Find mac-address
         ios_command:
           provider: "{{ cli }}"
           commands:
             - show mac add | i d83b
         register: sh_mac_res
```

sh_mac_res is variable contain string like this:

```
 "22    18a9.0530.d83b    DYNAMIC     Fa0/17"
```

How can I  put **18a9.0530.d83b** into a variable?

```
set_facts:
  mac_address: {{ sh_mac_res.stdout }}.........????
```

What should I use? regex_search or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Python `split()` function and select the second element of the resulting list:

```
- set_fact:
    mac_address: "{{ sh_mac_res.stdout.split()[1] }}"
```